# Can I use AWS-XRay to trace MySQL queries without Tomcat or Spring?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I'm running some SQL queries in an AWS Lambda, and was hoping to utilize AWS-XRay's tracing capabilities to get some more detailed information on these calls.

[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-sqlclients.html) shows examples of configuration with Spring and Tomcat, but neither of which makes sense to use in my obviously serverless and supposed-to-be lightweight Lambda.  Here's how I establish my connections currently:

```
public Connection getDatabaseConnection(String jdbcUrl, String dbUser, String dbPassword) throws SQLException
{
    return DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);
}

try (Connection connection = getDatabaseConnection(getJdbcUrl(), getDbUser(), getDbPassword()))
{
    try(ResultSet results = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT stuff FROM whatever LIMIT 1))
    {
        return (results.getLong(1));
    }
}
```

Is there any way to utilize AWS-XRay SQL tracing in my use case?

Comment: I added XRay support to Apache Camel recently and added some notes on how to achieve the same result as the MySQL statement interceptor in the [PR ticket](https://github.com/apache/camel/pull/2072#issuecomment-343239257) without the need of the Tomcat interceptor

Answer (score 2):

I think one approach would be to use a MySQL statement interceptor:
https://github.com/spullara/mysql-connector-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mysql/jdbc/StatementInterceptor.java

You can use AWSXRay.beginSubsegment() in preProcess() method and then AWSXRay.endSubsegment() in the postProcess().

Would be a nice addition to [AWS X-Ray SDK for Java](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java) which is in open source. 
in case you get it working.

For reference of spring based implementation for X-Ray: [DataSource based intereceptor](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-xray-recorder-sdk-sql-mysql/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/xray/sql/mysql/TracingInterceptor.java)

You can use the statementinterceptors property as part of the connection URL to intercept the statement as documented here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

**Update**
My teammate pointed out, a newer version of StatementInterceptor is available:
https://github.com/spullara/mysql-connector-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mysql/jdbc/StatementInterceptorV2.java
You may want to use that.